# That's a lot of work... or not?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, cryptic-clues, metapuzzles

Answer the following clues to find a word (or 2 in the case of the 3rd) and find the common theme connecting the answers:

> 1. Jack of all
> 2. My prefix makes you miss school
>    While my infix is one less of a spice
>    And my suffix is the end of your journey
>    When you say see you later, alligator!
> 3. As soon as someone is identified as an ______, they no longer are.
> 4. [image: img1] + [image: img2] + [image: img3]
> 5. Use action and hold on
> 6. Barney wait-for-it Stinson
> 7. 20-21-13-2-12-5 + 23-5-5-4

Hint 1:

> 3 is a quote by George Carlin

Note: Heights of the images don't matter. Otherwise the images are fine. I'll keep trying to see if I can fix the third image. Here is a link to the third image (and that is exactly how I want the image to be): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GcXt.jpg

Comment: I think I need some help with including the images...

Comment: You're linking to the Imgur album page, not the image itself. Right click on the image and click "copy image address", and use that instead. (Or just upload the images through SE's post interface.)

Comment: Thanks @Deusovi! Although they're supposed to come one next to the other, I at least got the images to show up.

Comment: You can make them smaller by adding `s`, `b`, `t`, `m`, `l`, or `h` just before the `.png`. (If you do this, I'd recommend making each one a link to the corresponding full-size image.)

Comment: I just tried it and I see what you mean. Let's see what I can do.

Comment: I think that's better for now. I'll keep trying to see if I can fix the third image.

Comment: Are you sure that [cryptic-clues] is correct? A cryptic clue is a very specific type of crossword clue, involving both wordplay and definition.

Comment: It's my first time making one, so I hope I have done it right. I can tell you rot 13(vg vaibyirf na nantenz naq gur qrsvavgvba). Also only one of the clues is supposed to be a cryptic clue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. > **Generalist** – or Jack of all trades.
2. > **Illuminator** – You miss school when you're **ill**; the spice is {c}**umin** and **ator** is the end of alligator and the "journey" through "alligator" is from "a to r".
3. > **Unsung Hero** – As said in the hint, this is a quotation by George Carlin.
4. > **Publicist** – The images show a **pub**, Long Island City or **LIC** for short and Misty. The last image is cropped, so it is just {M}**ist**{y}.
5. > **Tenacious** – To hold on is to be tenacious and it is an anagram of "use action". (The anagram isn't indicated, but the OP has posted a comment to that effect under the question.)
6. > **Legendary** – That's what Barney Stinson says often. (Found by AHKieran)
7. > **Tumbleweed** – Numbers indicate the position of letters in the alphabet: 1 → A; 2 → B; 3 → C; ...; 26 → Z. (Found by AHKieran)

These are ...

> ... [badges](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges) that have not yet been awarded on Puzzling Stack Exchange. Getting them can be a lot of work, but nobody seems to have put it into getting these badges yet. (I doubt, however, that Unsung Hero, Tenacious and Tumbleweed require a lot of work or that you can even plan to get them.)
>
>  Credit to Nicolás Magno, who found out that all of the badges hadn't been awarded yet, see his answer. I had found only that the answers were Badge names.

Comment: Yes! The answers to all the clues are correct! But there is a little something more to the common theme. You will get it if you observe the (Onqtrf) page a little more closely!

Comment: Check my answer, it might help you complete yours!

Comment: Yay! You got it! And that is what I meant by the title: (Zbfg bs gur onqtrf erdhver n ybg bs jbex, juvyr Hafhat Ureb, Granpvbhf naq Ghzoyrjrrq qba'g arrq nal jbex). I will accept your answer in a little while!

Comment: Btw, I would love to get some feedback on the puzzle. I understand the cryptic clue was not the best, but what do you think of the remaining clues and the puzzle itself? Is there any way I can improve for the next time? :)

Comment: It's a good puzzle. The seven parts are of varying difficulty and quality: 7 is a write-in; 1 is a bit loose and cropping Misty is a bit cheeky. (Which parts are good and bad or easy and hard probably depends a great deal on who solves it.) It doesn't really matter, though, because you don't need all the answers to find the theme and therefore you can solve the remaining parts backwards once you know what you're looking for. That's what I did and it would have been even easier if I had spotted the exact nature of the overall answer.

Comment: Cryptic clues are often a point of debate: They follow rather rigid rules and if you tag something as cryptic clue, people expect you to adhere to these rules. In your case, the anagram needs to be indicated, because anagrams are just one of several kinds of wordplay that can be used. There's also a mismatch between the definition ("hold on", a verb) and the answer (an adjective).

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer by **M Oehm**

> The theme might be **zero** or **none**. None of the Badges had been earned.

Comment: Ah,that's a good observation. (But I have an Unsung Hero badge, albeit not here on PSE.)

Comment: Great job identifying it! Here's a +1.

Comment: And @MOehm, I did not know about that, I only checked the PSE badges page, sorry :P

Comment: No need to apologise. This site is PSE and your puzzle works well.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured it out but here are my thoughts, perhaps combined with someone else's we can figure it out:

1.

> Trades? (Jack of all Trades)

2.

> Prefix - not sure. Infix - Four (Chinese Five Spice - 1). Suffix - Bye? Can't think of any words ending in fourbye so I may be wrong.

3.

> Don't know

4.

> Bar City Misty. Don't know what this means though.

5.

> Don't know

6.

> Legend/Legendary

7.

> Tumble Weed (numbered positions of letters in the alphabet)

Theme:

> Spaghetti Western films? (complete guess)

Comment: Third one could be a rot13(fgenatre)

Comment: You got 6 and 7 right! Awesome! But the others still need work.

Comment: for number 4, third pic is - ROT3(zvfgl sebz cbxrzba pnegbba)